# Once I create a web app using Django + Python can I alter models?

Tags: python, django

If I am creating my first python web app using Django, am I able to at a later date, edit/change up models/views and have the program do so accordingly? Do I have to run a specific command to update my web app? Or Do I need to create the web application the way I want too right away?

I have been trying to google this, but am unable to come to a concrete answer. I am just using tutorials, but will want to add my own features at a later date, and want to make sure I do not need to create another app for example. Please remember, I am still fairly new.

Comment: Yes, it is called a migration. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/

Comment: Yes, with the potential exception of the user model - if you think you might need to change that later you should extend it before running the initial migrations.

Comment: Thanks guys! Very helpful, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry I was very new, I did not expect to get down voted so quickly, as plenty of guides have different answers/questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alter models.  Then you should use `manage.py makemigrations` to construct migrations which reflect the changes you made.  Use `manage.py migrate` to then apply the changes to the database.

It's important to notice that "this is the way it works."  You build your models, then make migrations both to initially create the corresponding tables and to make any subsequent changes to them.  *(It is also possible to scrape from an existing database.)*

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand, this is why I was unable to find this answer on google, makemigrations and migrations! Thanks again!